# How JS use Object variables without knowing their names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I m using an example code of an android app,
One of the asset files is HTML that contain 2 JS codes
the first JS code is hosted online on Wikitudes servers, and the second is local code in the HTML file itself
I don't understand how the local code is good for something, as the names of the variables are not mandatory, when i change the name of the vars the code still works!
How is this possible?
I m used to Java and CPP where if you want to use object variables you have to know its name!
this is the file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="https://www.wikitude.com/libs/architect.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    AR.context.onLocationChanged = function(lat, lon, alt, acc) {
            var src = new AR.ImageResource("assets/marker_idle.png");
            var marker = new AR.ImageDrawable(src, 2.5, {
                zOrder: 0,
                opacity: 1.0
            });
            var markerLocation = new AR.GeoLocation(31.261809, 34.794700, 302.5);
            var markerObject = new AR.GeoObject(markerLocation, {
                drawables: {
                    cam: [marker]
                }
            }); 
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The strange thing is that even if i change the name of the var "markerObject" to something else, e.g. "myMarkerObject", the code still works! how is that possible?
As it seems - the **online** javascript code has no way to know the names of the variables that are defined in the"onLocationChanged" function in the  **local** javascript code.
so how is the variables used?
what are those variables (such as "markerObject") good for? if no other object know their names?
please save me from this terror

Comment: It doesn't matter what variables you're using, it matters what functions they are attached to, such as `new AR.GeoObject` with variable name `markerObjects`.

Comment: So, `src`, `marker`, and `markerLocation` are all being used in the code. The only one not being used is `markerObject`, and that's likely just because instantiating `GeoObject` has side effects that make whatever this code does, do its thing. So `markerObject` is a throw away object.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan could you kindly please por favor give an example of how instantiation can have this kind of side effects? cause it dont seem possible to me

Comment: Well, `markerObject`'s constructor could make changes to anything in its object graph. For instance, it could make changes to the `ImageDrawable` via its reference to `marker` passed in via the second parameter to the constructor. I have no idea what any of these objects actually do (I don't know Android or Java), but I've seen code that does that...